# Why autowiring bean is null?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I write test for my application:

```
public class CandidateServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    CandidateService candidateService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() throws Exception{
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "test/BeanConfig.xml");//I think here I load context

        UtilMethods.createTestDb();

    }

    @Test
    public void add(){
        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
        candidate.setName("testUser");
        candidateService.add(candidate);//NullPointerException  here
        List<Candidate> candidates = candidateService.findByName(candidate.getName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(candidates);
    }
}
```

in row

```
candidateService.add(candidate);//Null entity here   here
```

candidateService is null.

test/BeanConfig.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based configuration)-->
        <context:annotation-config />


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.jpa" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="package com.epam.hhsystem.services" />

        <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
        <import resource="data.xml" />

    </beans>
```

data.xml - info about hibernate,

class of CandidateService:

```
package com.epam.hhsystem.services;
     ...
    @Transactional
    @Service("candidateService")
    public class CandidateService {

        @Autowired
        private CandidateDao candidateDao;//package com.epam.hhsystem.jpa

        @Autowired
        private VacancyDao vacancyDao;//package com.epam.hhsystem.jpa

        @Autowired
        private SkillDao skillDao;//package com.epam.hhsystem.jpa

        @Autowired
        private EventDao eventDao;//package com.epam.hhsystem.jpa

        @Autowired 
        UtilService utilService;//package com.epam.hhsystem.services


        public void add(Candidate candidate) {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            String login = auth.getName();
            User user =  utilService.getOrSaveUser(login);
            candidate.setAuthor(user);
            candidateDao.add(candidate);
        }

        ....
    }
```

Can you help me?

**UPDATE**

I rewrite code so:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml"})
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{

    @Autowired
    CandidateService candidateService;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialize() throws Exception{

        UtilMethods.createTestDb();

    }

    @Test
    public void add(){
        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
        candidate.setName("testUser");
        candidateService.add(candidate);
        List<Candidate> candidates = candidateService.findByName(candidate.getName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(candidates);
    }
}
```

And I have so trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService.add(CandidateService.java:56)
at com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3796612d.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
at com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$afe33393.add(<generated>)
at com.epam.hhhsystem.services.CandidateServiceTest.add(CandidateServiceTest.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Did you tell your JUnit to use Spring test runner? What annotations do you have on CandidateServiceTest?

Comment: Small remark regarding your config `<context:annotation-config />` is already implied by using a `<context:component-scan ../>`. And instead of multiple `<context:component-scan ../>` simply use a single one with a , seperated list of packages to scan.

Comment: Your service assumes that there is an `Authentication` object, but there isn't one. You need to set one before your test starts, either in your `@Test` or by using a `@Before` method.

Comment: It is not clear for me. Can you write code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your testcase is written wrong. Use the framework don't work around it. Use Springs Test Support classes to load and autowire your testcase, instead of trying to work your way around it.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml"})
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    CandidateService candidateService;

    @Test
    public void add(){
        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();
        candidate.setName("testUser");
        candidateService.add(candidate);//NullPointerException  here
        List<Candidate> candidates = candidateService.findByName(candidate.getName());
        Assert.assertNotNull(candidates);
    }
}
```

I strongly suggest a read of the [Spring Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) and in this case especially [the section covering testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

Next to not using the framework properly you aren't setting your initial state properly. You are writing a unit/integration test and your `CandidateService` implementation expects that a Spring Security Authentication object is available. You aren't setting one before your test is run so that will result in a `NullPointerException`.

Add a `@Before` method which will set it before your test method and an `@After` method which cleans up after that. (Or do it in your test method but remember to cleanup properly!).

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    TestingAuthenticationToken testToken = new TestingAuthenticationToken("testUser", "");
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(testToken);
}

@After
public void cleanUp {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
}
```

Comment: AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTest - can you write maven dependency ?

Comment: The `spring-test` artifact.

Comment: AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests  maybe?

Comment: I would say there is a mistake here: <context:component-scan base-package="package com.epam.hhsystem.services" />. It should not have "package" in there.

Comment: Can you explain how Did you ubderstand problem with spring security?

Comment: and second question: How can I disable spring security in test config?

Comment: I don't understand your question "problem with spring security"? But in case you want to unit test it, there is already an brief answer for that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360520/unit-testing-with-spring-security

Comment: Can you explain how Did you ubderstand that problem with spring security?

Comment: I don't see in my config mentions about spring-security.

Comment: Your code is referencing Spring Security  (`SecurityContextHolder` is from Spring Security) and as Spring Security expects certain things for an executing thread to be set it fails. If you don't set the precondition for your test correctly it will fail.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the annotation for test class that you put here. Normally, to run test class in Spring context, you need to use following annotation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
// This will run necessary job to load the context and inject bean into your test
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/test-bundle-context.xml") 
// This specify the configuration used, you can use the java-config style as well (but only for Spring 3.1)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManager", defaultRollback = true) 
// If you want to test the transaction, otherwise, this is not necessary
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS) 
// depend on your test natural, you can set difference propagation.
```

Component scan doesn't help anything in your test.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Comment: give me maven dependency please

Comment: It should be the same as Deinum mentioned, see my answer edited above

Answer (score 1):

I guess your BeanConfig.xml is wrong, because it contains "package":

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="package com.epam.hhsystem.services" />
```

Change it to:

```
// package removed     
<context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.services" />
```

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and the cause turned out to be none of the answers above. Turns out my IDE had inserted `import org.junit.Test` instead of `import org.testng.annotations.Test`. Trivial but very hard to track down.