# Injecting principal in controller test

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I would like to inject principal object in controller test, but it is always null. Im already setting the authentication object to SecurityContextHolder

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

this is my setup before

```
@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

 @Before
    public void abstractControllerSetUp() {
        securityUser = getPrincipal();
        authentication = logIn();
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }
```

but when I call

```
mockMvc.perform(put("/partner/notifications/activate")
                .content(toJson(command))
                .with(user(securityUser))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

the principal is alwyas null, it works when app running.

```
@PutMapping("/activate")
    public void activateNotification(@RequestBody NotificationCommand command, @AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
```

Comment: have you looked at @WithMockUser (section 11.2) https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360520/unit-testing-with-spring-security

Answer (score 3):

In Spring 4.3.2, `MockMvcRequestBuilders` has a method called `principal()`. Use that instead of `with(user())`.

```
mockMvc.perform(put("/partner/notifications/activate")
            .content(toJson(command))
            .principal(securityUser)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :

```
User user = new User(userName,userPassword, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("YOUR_ROLES...."));
TestingAuthenticationToken testingAuthenticationToken = new TestingAuthenticationToken(user,null);
```

Then

```
mockMvc.perform(put("/partner/notifications/activate").principal(testingAuthenticationToken))
```