# How can I check Spring Security for user authentication and get roles from Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, spring, authentication, authorization, spring-security

I'm using Spring, Spring Security, BlazeDS, Flex and spring-flex.

I know that I can call `channelSet.login()` and `channelSet.logout()` to hook into Spring Security for authentication. `channelSet.authenticated` apparently only knows about the current Flex session, as it always starts off as *false*, until you call `channelSet.login()`.

What I want to do:

1. Check from Flex to know if a user is already in a session.
2. If so, I want their username and roles.

**UPDATE**
I just thought I'd add details of the solution I used from [brd6644](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41754/brd6644)'s answer below, so that this might be easier for someone else who looks this up. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248562/when-using-spring-security-what-is-the-proper-way-to-obtain-current-username-i) StackOverflow answer to make the `SecurityContext` injectable. I won't be rewriting the code from that answer in this one, so go look at it for the `SecurityContextFacade`.

*securityServiceImpl.java*

```
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {
    private SecurityContextFacade securityContextFacade;

    @Secured({"ROLE_PEON"})
    public Map<String, Object> getUserDetails() {
        Map<String,Object> userSessionDetails = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        SecurityContext context = securityContextFacade.getContext();
        Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();

        ArrayList roles = new ArrayList();
        GrantedAuthority[] grantedRoles = userDetails.getAuthorities();
        for (int i = 0; i < grantedRoles.length; i++) {
            roles.add(grantedRoles[i].getAuthority());
        }

        userSessionDetails.put("username", userDetails.getUsername());
        userSessionDetails.put("roles", roles);
        return userSessionDetails;
    }
}
```

*securityContext.xml*

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <!-- Don't authenticate Flex app -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/flexAppDir/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <!-- Don't authenticate remote calls -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/messagebroker/amfsecure" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
</security:http>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

<bean id="securityService" class="ext.domain.project.service.SecurityServiceImpl">
    <property name="securityContextFacade" ref="securityContextFacade" />
</bean>
<bean id="securityContextFacade" class="ext.domain.spring.security.SecurityContextHolderFacade" />
```

*flexContext.xml*

```
<flex:message-broker>
    <flex:secured />
</flex:message-broker>

<flex:remoting-destination ref="securityService" />
<security:http auto-config="true" session-fixation-protection="none"/>
```

*FlexSecurityTest.mxml*

```
<mx:Application ... creationComplete="init()">

    <mx:Script><![CDATA[
        [Bindable]
        private var userDetails:UserDetails; // custom VO to hold user details

        private function init():void {
            security.getUserDetails();
        }

        private function showFault(e:FaultEvent):void {
            if (e.fault.faultCode == "Client.Authorization") {
                Alert.show("You need to log in.");
                // show the login form
            } else {
                // submit a ticket
            }
        }
        private function showResult(e:ResultEvent):void {
            userDetails = new UserDetails();
            userDetails.username = e.result.username;
            userDetails.roles = e.result.roles;
            // show user the application
        }
    ]]></mx:Script>

    <mx:RemoteObject id="security" destination="securityService">
        <mx:method name="getUserDetails" fault="showFault(event)" result="showResult(event)" />
    </mx:RemoteObject>

    ...
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [Spring Blazeds integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) , you can implement getUserDetails method using org.springframework.flex.security.AuthenticationResultUtils.

```
public Map<String, Object> getUserDetails() {  
 return AuthenticationResultUtils.getAuthenticationResult();
}
```

Comment: This was MUCH better than what I had going on. It worked very well and saved a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a secured Spring service method that returns the current user's roles information.  Let the Flex app invoke that when the application starts up.  If you receive a FaultEvent due to a security error, then prompt the user to authenticate and use ChannelSet.login().

Comment: Nice idea, will def try this.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog, I followed this before Spring had a flex module, which solves this problem nicely.  Hopefully it'll provide you a few gems which might help.

[GridShore Blog](http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/05/11/integrating-flex-3-with-spring-security-formerly-known-as-acegi/)

Comment: The people commenting on his blog posts seem to be having the same problems that I was; mainly that logging in and out was easy from Flex, but noticing an existing session wasn't. brd6644's solution worked perfectly for this.