# spring security. display user name on every page

Tags: spring, security, jsp, model-view-controller, spring-security

I want to store user information after logging in and to display my login and username on every page (using jsp). How can I get access in my jsp views to the session bean that would store information of the user that is logged in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the [authentication tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6174)

> This tag allows access to the current
>   Authentication object stored in the
>   security context. It renders a
>   property of the object directly in the
>   JSP. So, for example, if the principal
>   property of the Authentication is an
>   instance of Spring Security's
>   UserDetails object, then using
>   <sec:authentication
>   property="principal.username" /> will
>   render the name of the current user.
>
> Of course, it isn't necessary to use
>   JSP tags for this kind of thing and
>   some people prefer to keep as little
>   logic as possible in the view. You can
>   access the Authentication object in
>   your MVC controller (by calling
>   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
>   and add the data directly to your
>   model for rendering by the view.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using spring security. After successful login put the UserDetails object in the session like so (This is usually the controller where you would forward if  login was successfull)

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
     .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true); //create a new session

// put the UserDetails object here.
session.setAttribute("userDetails", principal);
```

In your JSP you can access the UserDetails object, like so:

```
<span class="message">Welcome ${userDetails.username}</span>
```

Comment: Is it really a good idea to go low lvl down to session objects instead of using Spring functionality that is supposed to handle it for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is a near duplicate to [When using Spring Security, what is the proper way to obtain current username (i.e. SecurityContext) information in a bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/248562/185093). The Spring endorsed method is

```
final String currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
```

but the linked discussion has alternatives.