# Spring annotation - Non logged in user redirect

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I need an annotation on method level which will redirect the current request to a login page if there is no user in session.

I also need to send the url to login page which will be the redirect location after successful login. (Obviously the current url with parameters)

Comment: In spring you usually define such behaviour with spring-security and its xml configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

There is a @Secured annotation which can help you. This [post](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-3-mvc-using-secured.html) can help you.

Comment: How would I check session attribute "User" for a particular method and if not found then redirect (with currentURL + Params)

Comment: It is already managed by Spring Security. Here is a [short explanation](http://pulkitsinghal.blogspot.com/2010/07/spring-security-redirect-back-to.html). For getting the current user, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248562/when-using-spring-security-what-is-the-proper-way-to-obtain-current-username-i)

Answer (score 0):

Less precise tutorial with spring security 2 : 
http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/method_level_security_in_spring

Annotation is the same : @Secured

Answer (score 0):

You should define something like the following.

```
<security:http auto-config='true'>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/style/**" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <security:http-basic/>
    <security:form-login login-page='/login' authentication-failure-url="/login?authfailed=true"/> 
    <security:logout />

</security:http>
```

`IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` is needed to allow access to login page. The first line allows access to images folder without authentication at all. This is just an example.

For more details take a look on spring documentation mentioned by @nico_ekito.

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be done with [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/reference.html) and the annotations you should use are `@Secured` and `@RolesAllowed`. Before you use the annotations, you need to integrate and configure Spring Security.

Take a look to [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) and [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html).