# Reference username after Spring LDAP Authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When using Spring Security, what is the proper way to obtain current username (i.e. SecurityContext) information in a bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248562/when-using-spring-security-what-is-the-proper-way-to-obtain-current-username-i)
>   [spring security how to retrieve username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317376/spring-security-how-to-retrieve-username)

I use spring ldap to authenticate my web app,

```
<ldap-server id="sss" port="389"
             url="ldap://ldap.example.com:389/ou=active,ou=employees,ou=people,o=example.com?uid?sub"/>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
            server-ref="sss"
            role-prefix="ROLE_">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

it works, but I don't know how to get the username filled in login page, because I want to display it on top of my page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

which returns searched entry.

Comment: and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()` gives the exact username.