# Keeping "current user" in threadlocal

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thread-local

I have a spring-mvc application that currently has two channels - web application and a REST service. Both have user's http session and I can easily get the "current user" in my service classes.

Now I need to develop another REST service where there are no http sessions and the current user depends on a request parameter. So the controller would read that request parameter and would find the current user.

Now I either need to:
1. modify my service layer methods to accept current user as parameter 
or 
2. just modify the class that gets the current user from the http session.

I also have the requirement to create an audit log and I'm going to use Spring AOP for that. The Aspect will need access to the "current user" too. So option #1 probably won't work for me and I will go with #2.

For option #2 I'll create an interceptor that will put the current user in a ThreadLocal variable. The controller for the new REST service will do the same and then in my service layer and in the audit log aspect I can get the current user from there.

I haven't done anything like this before and was wondering if there is a better approach. Or what kind of issues I should expect with this approach.

I will appreciate any comments and ideas.

Oz

Here is how I currently get the current user:

```
@Override
public User getCurrentUser()
{
    Authentication currentUser = getAuthentication();

    return userService.getByLoginName(currentUser.getName());
}


protected Authentication getAuthentication()
{
    return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
}
```

Comment: Some code might help. I understand you are accessing the http session from your service layer, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I updated my post with a sample.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823761/spring-mvc-getting-principal-from-security-context-in-service-layer

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't answer my question. I already have a service that gets the current user from the http session and I don't have direct calls to http session or spring context in any other place. The problem is that I can't use this approach any more because of the new REST service.

Comment: you should pass the user as a parameter to your service methods from your controller. I don't see the problem with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simple way to do what you need is to configure a servlet filter for your new REST webservice to populate the `SecurityContextHolder` with an `Authentication` object build from request parameters.

You can read this : http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e2171 for more details.

With this solution you don't need to modify the code to retrieve the current user. (note that the `SecurityContextHolder` is already using a `ThreadLocal` to store the `SecurityContext` and so the `Authentication`)

Comment: Thanks! That's actually the easiest way to do it. Instead of using a filter I can set the authentication object directly in my REST controller because the request is XML format and will require additional transformation.