# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() is null on Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring MVC application where I'm exposing an endpoint, and a small library where I wrote some common functionality.

I have an utility class like this:

```
class SecurityUtil {
    public static Principal getPrincipal(){
       return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
              .getPrincipal();
    } 
}
```

And from the Controller I'm doing something like:

```
 class MyController {

      public ResponseEntity<Void> myEndpoint(){
           // do something
           Principal principal = SecurityUtil.getPrincipal();
           // use the principal information for some audit processes
      }
 }
```

In this case the `Principal` is null, but if replace my code like this:

```
 class MyController {

      public ResponseEntity<Void> myEndpoint(){
           // do something
           Principal principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                                      .getAuthentication()
                                                      .getPrincipal();
           // use the principal information for some audit processes
      }
 }
```

In this case the `Principal` is not null and it has the information that I need.
Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: I just tested and it does not matter. I'm still getting a null value for it

Comment: Are you accessing `SecurityUtil` as a spring bean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was going through the same problem and then I have solved it in following manner.

Create `UserService` interface

```
public interface UserService {
    String getLoggedInUserName();
    User getLoggedInUser();
}
```

Provide an implementation for `UserService`, However, you can also it without creating the interface and by simply creating UserService as a class.

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService { 

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String getLoggedInUserName() {
        try {
            return getLoggedInUser().getUsername();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Please Log in", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User getLoggedInUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof User) {
            return (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User is not authenticated; Found " + authentication.getPrincipal() + " of type " + authentication.getPrincipal().getClass() + "; Expected type User");
        }
    }

}
```

And the calling `userService.getLoggedInUserName()` by auto wiring `UserService`

```
@Autowired UserService userService
```

Update:
If you are getting them in your controller only then you can simply pass Principal principal as a method argument to your controller method instead of getting it from the security context. It will be auto-wired to controller automatically and later on you can pass it your service methods. This way is also considered a good practice [Spring MVC, getting principal from security context in service layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823761/spring-mvc-getting-principal-from-security-context-in-service-layer)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myEndpoint", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<Void> myEndpoint(Principal principal){
   // do something
   // use the principal information for some audit processes
}
```

Comment: mmm this is not working for me either. Is UserService and UserServiceImpl in a jar? or is directly on the MVC project

Comment: It is directly in my project, but I think having them in the jar will also not cause any problem I have tested it.

Comment: If you are getting them in your controller only then you can simply pass `Principal principal` as a method argument to your controller method instead of getting it from security context.

Comment: Thanks Naresh Joshi, I had an error in my application context, now it's working