# Spring Secuiry Database Authentication casting Spring User to Domain User

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've been having some trouble figuring this one out.

I've got an multitenant system where users are organized into organizations. Within that organization the usernames must be unique. Otherwise, two organizations can have the same user name.

I've got spring security hooked up with the jdbc-user-service and all that works fine.  My problems start when I'm trying to get the current user.

I took a look at [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248562/when-using-spring-security-what-is-the-proper-way-to-obtain-current-username-i) that leverages spring 3 and the Principal object as a method parameter.  This works great, except a Principal doesn't have enough information! First, usernames aren't unique in my usecase, also having easy access to the organization that the user belongs to would be great.

A little more searching dug up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/best-practice-for-getting-active-users-userdetails) awesome answer.  The problem with this is the same problem as before. It relies on the Principal object, which just doesn't have enough info.

(here's the magic)

```
@Override
 public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
                     ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                     NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                     WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {

      if (this.supportsParameter(methodParameter)) {
          Principal principal = webRequest.getUserPrincipal();
          return (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();
      } else {
          return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
      }
 }
```

Is there a good way to override the User object to use my own? Am i stuck writing a custom UserDetailService? Is there a better approach than continuing to walk down this path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your User object inherit UserDetails(or use a wrapper) and use it as principal.

e.g.

```
public class MyCustomUser implements UserDetails {
    // ..
}
```

Make a custom UserDetailsService that returns your User object:

```
@Service
public class MyCustomUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomUserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userDAO.getByUsername(username);
    }
}
```

Now you can extract your user:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();

MyCustomUser user = (MyCustomUser)principal;

user.myCustomMethod();
```

Comment: Is there a cleaner way than referencing by username? I know i can play games with the 'username' for ex, I can have some sort of string cat with the organization or just convert the userid to a string and use that, but then i won't be loading by username (per the method name)

Comment: Eh, disregard. It'd be nice to have duplicate usernames across organizations, but that'd require some way of figuring out what the organization is so it can be combined with the username. I'll just name the username unique.  Thanks for the answer!