# What is the proper way to get User object details in jsp page in Spring Framework(4)?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

How to get User Object details in JSP page? Below code works fine in Spring Framework 3 but gives error in Spring 4.

Code Block

```
<span class="header-label">${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal.firstName} ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.principal.lastName}</span>
```

Error given in Spring 4 (Eclipse IDE) although works fine when deployed

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The method getPrincipal() is undefined for the type 
     Principal
    - javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a 
     type
    - javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved to a 
     type
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your expression. At best, with the help of some javadocs ([HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal()) and [Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html)), the expression could be:

```
${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}
```

You can try this.

But a `Principal` is not the exact equivalent of a user. It's more of an authentication perspective of a `Subject` (which is roughly the user). It represents one of the means a subject has to sign in. For all we know, the name property could be the username or a credit card number.

It's really unlikely you'll get the first and last names from the principal though.

Comment: We are using custom user detail service for spring which retrieves all the attributes required for the custom UserDetails object. So i need to get the values using Principal which is equivalent to User in our case...

Comment: Maybe these links can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248562/when-using-spring-security-what-is-the-proper-way-to-obtain-current-username-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764545/how-to-get-active-users-userdetails