# How can I get the ID attribute of a logged in User and set it as a foreign key in the database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-security

So here is the thing. I have 2 tables in the database: **User** and **Client**.

A user can add one or many clients in the database. So what I want is when a user will add a client - the function will retrieve the **id** of the logged in User and add it as a **foreign key** in the client table.

I have already done the `OneToMany` Mapping.

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postficheclient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createClient(@RequestBody Client newClient) {
    // newClient.setUser(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<Client>(clientservices.save(newClient), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

With that function, it adds a `null` value in the `Client` table.

Can someone help me, please?

PS: I use the spring security system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using Spring Security, what is the proper way to obtain current username (i.e. SecurityContext) information in a bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248562/when-using-spring-security-what-is-the-proper-way-to-obtain-current-username-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Spring Security, you can get the logged client through SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

and you can get various details from:

- getPrincipal() - usually the user identifier
- getAuthorities() - the authorities
- getDetails() - additional user details

The infos put in the various fields depends how spring security handle your authentication mecanism, but I guess you can find what you need for in principal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @slemoine . I have used  **getPrincipal()**...Indeed, it retrieves every details about the currentUser except the **ID**. And this is the attribute i actually need.

Comment: Well I guess if you have the username which should be unique or email, you can retrieve it from database then